# Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Tags: vbscript, messagebox

My code is as follows:

```
a=msgbox("Do you like waffles",4+16,"Waffles")
Do While a=vbno
a
Loop
if a=vbyes then
b=msgbox("Do you like pancakes",4+16,"Pancakes")
Do While b=vbno
b
loop
if b=vbye then
c=msgbox("Do you like French toast",4+16,"French toast")
Do While c=vbno
c
Loop
else
d-msgbox("good",0+16,"YAY!")
end if
```

I know it is basic, but it comes up with the error message: "Error: Expected 'End'"
But as you can see 'end' is at the start of line 17, if it is something I haven't seen some where else in the code that might be causing this. I'm kind of new to this language and was putting things I knew how to do into a semi-useful paten. 
I saved it as a .bat file and ran it using cmd.

Comment: That is not C++... VB?

Comment: The tag "C++" is wrong, it seems like VBScript. And in VBScript, a main wrong thing is to not have `option explicit` at top.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the original code posted in the question (as I'm writing this):

```
a=msgbox("Do you like waffles",4+16,"Waffles")
Do While a=vbno
a
Loop
if a=vbyes then
b=msgbox("Do you like pancakes",4+16,"Pancakes")
Do While b=vbno
b
loop
if b=vbye then
c=msgbox("Do you like French toast",4+16,"French toast")
Do While c=vbno
c
Loop
else
d-msgbox("good",0+16,"YAY!")
end if
```

A main error cause seems to be a notion that one can assign a *definition* to a variable. Well one can, but not in that way. Here is corrected code:

```
option explicit

dim answer
do
    answer = msgbox("Do you like waffles",4+16,"Waffles")
    if answer = vbYes then exit do
    answer = msgbox("Do you like pancakes",4+16,"Pancakes")
    if answer = vbYes then exit do
    answer = msgbox("Do you like French toast",4+16,"French toast")
    if answer = vbYes then exit do
loop
call msgbox( "good",0+16,"YAY!" )
```

There are however umpteen zillion ways to prepare food, and so also with code, plus, it's not clear if the above *is the intention*, but I guess it's pretty close.

At any rate, it's code that works and that you can build further on

<del>Note that VBScript documentation is now only available as a CHM compiled help file, called **["script56.chm"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764)**.</del>

The VBScript documentation is both available as a handy CHM compiled help file, called **["script56.chm"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764)**, as well as **[online in the MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=vs.84%29)**.

Note: you need to save the source code as a **.vbs** file.

Comment: The documentation is still available [online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=vs.84%29).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: thanks. it was still disappeared last i checked. a welcome change, for change! :)